# Redirection login cookie or pass in data via POST?

Tags: python, html, web, python-requests

I’m trying to use Python’s requests library to automatically get my grades from a university website. The URL is https://acorn.utoronto.ca/sws/transcript/academic/main.do?main.dispatch, but there are several redirects. I have the following simple code but it doesn't seem to be doing what I want.

```
import requests

payload = {"user" : "username", "pass" : "password"}
r = requests.post("https://acorn.utoronto.ca/sws/transcript/academic/main.do?main.dispatch", data= payload)
print(r.text)
```

The output is as follows:

```
C:\Users\johnp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe 

C:/Users/johnp/Desktop/git_stuff/16AugRequests/acorn_requests.py <html> <head> </head> <body onLoad="document.relay.submit()"> <form method=post action="https://weblogin.utoronto.ca/" name=relay> <input type=hidden name=pubcookie_g_req value="b25lPWlkcC51dG9yYXV0aC51dG9yb250by5jYSZ0d289Q0lNRl9TaGliYm9sZXRoX1BpbG90JnRocmVlPTEmZm91cj1hNWEmZml2ZT1HRVQmc2l4PWlkcC51dG9yYXV0aC51dG9yb250by5jYSZzZXZlbj1MMmxrY0M5QmRYUm9iaTlTWlcxdmRHVlZjMlZ5Um05eVkyVkJkWFJvJmVpZ2h0PSZob3N0bmFtZT1pZHAudXRvcmF1dGgudXRvcm9udG8uY2EmbmluZT0xJmZpbGU9JnJlZmVyZXI9KG51bGwpJnNlc3NfcmU9NSZwcmVfc2Vzc190b2s9LTczODQ3MDk2OCZmbGFnPTA=">
```

You do not have Javascript turned on,   please click the button to continue.

Am I going about this the right way? I feel like I should be trying to pass a cookie instead, but how would I get the cookie?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: this is the stuff I get from Firefox:
[Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIHWl.png)

Does this mean I need to fill out the entire form as parameters in the request?

Comment: Use an http proxy, or a tool like Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox's Firebug.  Use the website normally and observe / record the requests made in order to reach your destination.  Then, recreate those requests via code.

Comment: I would suggest you use selenium

Comment: Maybe using a headless browser? http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: @masnun I have used selenium before and it works, but I was wondering if there was a "lower level" appraoch

Comment: I think the issue here is that requests module can handle http requests but can not execute JS. So not sure if requests module would be any help.

Comment: @masnun oh is that an actual thing? I was under the impression that requests can do anything the browser can do (just behind the scenes).  Is there a way of doing this in JS (if that even makes sense)? thanks

Comment: To execute JS, you need a browser engine, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can try logging in then getting whatever page you want, there is more more data to be posted which you can get with *bs4*:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://weblogin.utoronto.ca/"
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update({"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content)
    data = {inp["name"]: inp["value"] for inp in soup.select("#query input[value]")}
    data["user"] = "username"
    data["pass"] = "password"
    post = s.post(url, data=data)
    print post
    print(post.content)
    protect = s.get("protected_page")
```

If we run the code and just print the data dict, you can see bs4 populates the required fields:

```
In [14]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ....:         s.headers.update({"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"})
   ....:         soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content,"html.parser")
   ....:         data = {inp["name"]:inp["value"] for inp in soup.select("#query input[value]")}
   ....:         data["user"] = "username"
   ....:         data["pass"] = "password"
   ....:         print(data)
   ....:     
{'seven': '/index.cgi', 'sess_re': '0', 'pre_sess_tok': '0', 'pass': 'password', 'four': 'a5', 'user': 'username', 'reply': '1', 'two': 'pinit', 'hostname': '', 'three': '1', 'pinit': '1', 'relay_url': '', 'nine': 'PInit', 'create_ts': '1471341718', 'referer': '', 'six': 'weblogin.utoronto.ca', 'first_kiss': '1471341718-777129', 'flag': '', 'five': '', 'post_stuff': '', 'creds_from_greq': '1', 'fr': '', 'eight': '', 'one': 'weblogin.utoronto.ca', 'file': ''}
```